# Some way to launch/display Notification Center from Quicksilver/Launchbar/Alfred?

Tags: notifications, quicksilver, launchbar

Pick your favorite launcher ([Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com), [LaunchBar](http://obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html), etc.)… My current choice is QS, but I'm ok with methods for another launcher. Is there a method to launch/call the notification center from one of these applications?

I know there is a way to set a global hotkey, but **another** global key is the last thing I need… my current ones are already causing conflicts with one or two apps, and I'll never remember another one. Is there a way to index whatever script or system action is triggered by the two-finger swipe from the edge of the screen?

Comment: I'm sure you could write an apple script, and then connect said script to quicksilver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Notification Center"
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Then, just save the script, then just add it to quicksilver's triggers.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, and it even works when I have [Bartender](http://www.macbartender.com/) hiding the menu bar icon.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it wouldn't be pretty, but what I would do is to just assign a really esoteric keyboard command (something guaranteed not to conflict with your existing shortcuts) and then write applescript to invoke that keystroke.

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "Some Rarely Used Letter" using {"command down, shift down, control down"}  --Or whatever
end tell
```

Then name the script "Open Notifications," add it to the QS catalogue and then you'll start bumping into it when you type "ONoto" or whatever you like to type.