# How can I use AppleScript to reshow the last OS X notification (in the notification banner)?

Tags: macos, applescript, notifications

After the notification disappears, I want to be able to make it appear again through AppleScript.

Comment: For the second part, see my answer to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92257/some-way-to-launch-display-notification-center-from-quicksilver-launchbar-alfred

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.